# некорректно работает @if в @foreach

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте.

Есть код, который выводит все элементы из бд, во время вывода проверяет на наличие значение в бд:

```
<div class="tickets-places">
    {{$i = 1}}
    @foreach($tickets as $t)

    @if($t->number != $i)
    <div class="one-place" id="game-place-{{$i}}" onclick="setplace(2,1, {{$i}}, {{$user->id}});">
        <span>{{$i}}</span>
    </div>
    @else

    <div class="one-place" id="game-place-" onclick="setplace(2,1, {{$i}}, {{$user->id}});">
        <span>test</span>
    </div>
    @endif
    {{$i = $i+1}}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Если значение есть в бд, то выводит test. Получается так, что если @if срабатывает, то он изменяет первые элемент или если в бд в двух строках установлено значение `$t->number` — он все равно выводит test только для первого значения. Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 0):

Для получения текущего индекса при обходе массива лучше используйте переменную `$loop`
вот тут статья поможет Вам с ним https://mattstauffer.co/blog/the-new-loop-variable-in-laravel-5-3

по вашей проблеме я думаю это связано с тем, что у Вас `$i` до старта цикла всегда 1. Я не могу точнее сказать, так как не знаю что при итерации цикла в переменной `$t->number`

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вариант:

```
<div class="tickets-places">
    @php
        $i = 1;
    @endphp
    @foreach($tickets as $t)

    @if($t->number != $i)
    <div class="one-place" id="game-place-{{$i}}" onclick="setplace(2,1, {{$i}}, {{$user->id}});">
        <span>{{$i}}</span>
    </div>
    @else

    <div class="one-place" id="game-place-" onclick="setplace(2,1, {{$i}}, {{$user->id}});">
        <span>test</span>
    </div>
    @endif
    @php
        $i += 1;
    @endphp
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Но лучше протестируйте этот вариант:

```
<div class="tickets-places">
@foreach($tickets as $t)
    @if($t->number != $loop->iteration)
        <div class="one-place" id="game-place-{{ $loop->iteration }}" onclick="setplace(2,1, {{ $loop->iteration }}, {{ $user->id }});">
            <span>{{ $loop->iteration }}</span>
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="one-place" id="game-place-" onclick="setplace(2,1, {{ $loop->iteration }}, {{ $user->id }});">
            <span>test</span>
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

p.s если у вас `$t->number` начинается с 1 используйте `$loop->iteration` если с 0 то `$loop->index`